# Oracle Golden Gate Replicat

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

can anyone help me? I want to run the replicat on my golden gate for windows. This is my replicat parameter

```
-- Replicat group --
replicat rep1
-- source and target definitions
ASSUMETARGETDEFS
--target database login --
userid ggtarget, password oracle
--file for discarded transaction --
discardfile C:\app\<name>\product\12.1.2ggtarget\oggcore_1\dirdat\rep1_discard.txt, append megabytes 10
--ddl support
DDL
--Specify table mapping --
map EAM.*, target EAM.*;
```

when i start the replicat, it say that the replicat is starting. but when i type info all, the replicat is stopped and the status said that is not currently running. how can i make it run?

Comment: Please format the code - the lines are wrapped and are unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the `ggserr.log` file for error messages.
2. The line with MAP command is incomplete. There should be something after the dot,

like:

```
map EAM.*, target EAM.*;
```

or:

```
map EAM.table, target EAM.table;
```

or:

```
map table, target table;
```

Comment: where i run it?

Comment: You have pasted a part of the parameter file. The parameter file contains syntax error and you should correct it. In the OGG there is an errorlog called ggserr.log which should contain the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check the report file for error

eg: view report rep1.rpt

It should contain the details of how the replicat parameter file is being parsed when trying to start the replicat.

However if you dont see any error code in report file or ggserr.log check your environment variables and parameter files location

Answer (score 0):

Try row with discard file.
Example
DISCARDFILE .dirrpt/discard.txt, APPEND, MEGABYTES 20

In You congif
discardfile C:\app<name>\product\12.1.2ggtarget\oggcore_1\dirdat\rep1_discard.txt, append megabytes 10

I think you lost comma after  append